# Can ようにする be used without する in colloquial speech?

Tags: abbreviations

I came across the following sentence:

> ご家族とよく相談して書いてくる**ように**。

For context: A teacher is talking to a class of students concerning a report they have to write.

I know that ように is often used at the end of a sentence to express a wish (especially in combination with どうか). However, I don't think the teacher is expressing a wish here. Could this ように be part of the expression ようにする ("to make sure that", "to try to") with the する missing? If so, is this a common pattern in colloquial speech?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 「ご家族{かぞく}とよく相談{そうだん}して書{か}いてくる**ように**。」

You are reading the end part correctly.  Something like 「してください」 or「しなさい」 is left unsaid as it is clear.

When a request (or a lighter kind of imperative) ends with 「ように」, it  always comes from a person of a higher status to a person of a lower status.

If a request is made the other way around, the speaker (who is lower in status) ***must*** add a polite verb phrase to 「ように」 such as 「お願｛ねが｝いします」、「してください」、「なさってください」, etc.

Answer (score 0):

よう is 様 meaning of which is appearance/looks.

- adjective+よう　＝　広いよう
- noun+よう　＝　山のよう
- verb+よう　＝　叫ぶよう

よう itself also has variation derived from conjugation.

- adjective form ような　＝　ような国
- adverb form ように　＝　ように働く
- ending form ようだ　＝　ようだ／ようです

Basically, よう describes situation in such appearance as expressed before hand or, let's say, a kind of picture imagined.

- 広いよう　seems/looks like wide
- 山のよう　seems/looks like mountain (exemplification)
- 叫ぶよう　seems/looks like to shout
- この家はちょっと狭いようだ。
- スーパーマンのようになれたらいいな。
- 彼がそんなことをするようには思えない。

From this original meaning, several additional meanings were developed.

1. way, method
2. reason, circumstances, grounds
3. purpose, aim, target
4. guess, supposition
5. softer imperative, request, solicitation
6. wish, hope

When sentence ends with ように, it is a deviation because grammatically correct way is ようだ format. It means that ending with ように has following part which is unsaid.

However, there is one exceptional case of 6. wish, hope, which is called as prayer sentence format.
Usually ように is attached to ます-sentences like below.

- 病気が早く治りますように。
- 試験に合格しますように。
- 素敵な恋が得られますように。

Most of  cases that ends by ように are 5. softer imperative or request.

- ように＋しなさい／してください／してみなさい／してごらん（なさい）
- ご家族とよく相談して書いてくるように。is this case.

For remaining cases, omission on ending part is rarely done.

1. 左手で支えるようにして右手を動かすのがポイントです。
2. 尖った角にはクッションを貼って、子供が怪我しないようにしました。
3. 毎朝野菜ジュースを飲んで、風邪をひかないようにすることが大事です。
4. あの人はすぐに風邪をひくようです。

I made this lengthy explanation for comprehensive understanding about ように.