# もう一度やってみるように+と what's the purpose of it?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, particles

もう一度やってみるようにと彼を励ましなさい。
I'm confused by the usage of と here.
もう一度やってみるように彼を励ましなさい。would be translated as "in order to make him try one more time,  please encourage him"  but with と I'm not sure how it'd be translated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> もう一度{いちど}やってみるように**と**彼{かれ}を励{はげ}ましなさい。

＝

> 『もう一度やってみるように。』**と**彼を励ましなさい。

The 「と」 is the quotative particle.  Whenever you encounter a 「と」 that seems difficult to understand, try putting the **preceding** phrase in quotation marks.  If that helped you comprehend the sentence, that 「と」 would be quotative 99% of the time.

Thus, the sentence means:

> Please encourage him to try to do it one more time.

or, more ***literally***,

> Please encourage him by saying "Try to do it one more time."

「～～ように」 as a request/order is explained here:

[Can ようにする be used without する in colloquial speech?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42782/can-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-be-used-without-%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-in-colloquial-speech/42784#42784)