# Meaning of Sentence Containing 〜ように

Tags: grammar

My grammar textbook contains the following sentence:

> 子供のころから、周りのことを考えて行動するようにと言われてきた。

What is the meaning of 〜ように in this sentence? There are many grammar rules involving 〜ように, and I wasn't able to determine which one is being used. Also, I would like to know what the whole sentence means. Thank you.

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42782/can-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-be-used-without-%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-in-colloquial-speech/42784#42784

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「ように」 in this context is a sentence-ender for a **request** or a light **imperative**.

「Verb Phrase + ように」＝「Verb Phrase + ようにしなさい」

> 子供{こども}のころから、周{まわ}りのことを考{かんが}えて行動{こうどう}するようにと言{い}われてきた。

＝

> 子供のころから、『周りのことを考えて行動するように！』**と**言われてきた。

The 「と」 is the quotative particle.

「周りのことを考えて行動するように！」 means:

"Conduct yourself by paying attention to all your surroundings!"

Thus, the sentence in question means:

> "Since I was a kid, I have always been told to conduct myself by paying attention to all my surroundings."

Comment: My textbook separates 〜ようにする・〜ようにしている and 〜ように…・〜ようにと…・〜よう… into two separate sections/rules. The former is defined as "Take care to ~/not to ~." and includes the example 集合時間に送れないようにしてください。The later is defined as "Express a demand or request" and includes the example 雑誌を買ってくるように頼まれた. Can these be thought of as the same grammar?